# Is there any way to convert CIImage to NSData without converting CIImage to UIImage or CGImage?

Tags: ios, nsdata, ciimage

**Is there any way to convert `CIImage` to `NSData` without converting `CIImage` to `UIImage` or `CGImage`?**

I am trying to make a camera app.
When capturing image, I process image with CIImage to give filter effect for image, edit some metadata and save it by PHAssetCreationRequest.

During this process I change imagedata to CIImage, CIImage to UIImage, UIImage to NSData. Apparently it takes times and I wanna save some time.

> **So, Is there any way to convert `CIImage` to `NSData` without converting `CIImage` to `UIImage` or `CGImage`?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CIContext has a method, JPEGRepresentationOfImage:colorSpace:options, to convert to NSData without converting to UIImage.

```
CIContext *contextToUse = ...;
NSData *imageData = [contextToUse JPEGRepresentationOfImage:image colorSpace:... options:@{}];
```

Comment: it works! Thanks very much. Though, it's not much faster than what i expected. `CIImage` to `CGImage` to `NSData` procedure is a bit faster than this method.

Comment: Well...behind the scenes all images are just 3d arrays. But you might want to also test with different CIContext types.

Comment: Okay, i will try, Thanks a lot!

Comment: CIImage defers rendering to the last possible moment, and, in your case getting the data out of CIImage is that moment when render has to happen.

Comment: @TKang Which method did you end up with?